# Open emacs in new window

Tags: window

When I type emacs it opens it in the terminal window.

I wish it to open in it's regular separate window (the color scheme look different in the terminal compared to the separate window).
I tried "emacs -c" and "emacsclient -c", both don't work.

How can i do that?

I am using centos 7 ( just starting to transition to linux) , there is no emacs ,so I install and the version I get is 24.3.1

Comment: What's the value of the `DISPLAY` variable in the shell where you ran emacs?

Comment: Display :0 unavailable, simulating -nw

Comment: Ok, so presumably your `DISPLAY` variable has a value of `:0`; this is the usual value and is most likely to be correct. What happens if you run some other program that wants to open an X window? Try running `xeyes`; you should see a pair of eyes that follow the mouse cursor.

Comment: i had to install, and when i type xeyes(as root)
 i get : No protocol specified
Error: Can't open display: :0

Comment: Don't run `xeyes` as root, but as your normal user. If it doesn't work then you've got some problem which isn't related to emacs.

Comment: ok it seems opening emacs as root automaticly opens it in the terminal

and when i opend it as sudo emacs it also did the same.

just had to open it as a regular user and type emacs.

Comment: Indeed! Programs running under other users cannot access your X display; this is by design.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to edit a configuration file which is owned by root, you can of course run emacs as root and just live with the fact that it's running in the terminal window.

However, there is a different way that you may find to be better. You can run emacs as yourself, and then open the file using [TRAMP](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/). TRAMP is usually used to open files located on remote computers, but it can also open files as root. For example, if you wanted to edit the file `/etc/hosts`, you would open it via TRAMP by specifying the path `/sudo:localhost:/etc/hosts`. This will prompt for your password just like the `sudo` program would, and saves you the hassle of leaving your current emacs session and starting a new one as root.

Comment: :: is a handy shortcut for :localhost: